# How to run code on your ViewModel using Caliburn.micro when a window is closing

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to using Caliburn.micro. I have a simple app that starts a process running in the ViewModel listening for some network messages. When the window closes I would like to stop the process in the Viewmodel from listening any longer.

Since the view is a UserControl how can I tell the window is closing so my ViewModel can clean up correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override `OnDeactivate` if your view model implements `IScreen` (or, equivalently, inherits from `Screen` if you want to have some logic ready). That method will be called when the screen gets deactivated, there's also the `bool` flag if the screen is only deactivating or closing.

Mind you, only the view models coming from your IoC container of choice in the bootstrapper
are going to have their lifetimes correctly hooked up. So if you get the VM that way, it will
properly have the `OnInitialize`, `OnActivate` and `OnDeactivate` called. If you instantiate the view model in any other way (e.g. manually) and you're using them in e.g. `Conductor`, you're out of luck...

Although I *think* that if you're using `IWindowManager` with view model implementing `IScreen`, it will try to enforce the regular lifetime cycle.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what "Trust me - I'm a Doctor" said I would recommend to have a look on `IDeactivate` interface.

You can implement that interface, have a `Deactivate` method and implement everything you need there.

[Caliburn documentation on lifecycle](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Screens,%20Conductors%20and%20Composition)